# What exactly does AVFoundation's AVAssetWriterInput expectsMediaDataInRealTime property do?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, video, avfoundation

I am working on an app that reads media data from disk, converts it into the appropriate pixel format and then passes it off to AVAssetWriter for compression and writing to disk. I am doing my own reading an interleaving and not using AVAssetReader. My reader ensures that exactly one frame's worth of video data and one frame's worth of audio data are presented in a serial fashion. The problem I am having is if I don't set the expectsMediaDataInRealTime property to **YES**, the video asset writer will always return **NO** for isReadyForMoreMediaData after exactly 30 frames. If I stop writing before 30 frames, it works fine and the output file is valid. However, if I set expectsMediaDataInRealTime to YES, it works perfectly for the entire duration, which can be several thousand frames. After starting a transcode operation with expectsMediaDataInRealTime set to YES, I watched the app's memory usage over the course of compressing a very long video and there wasn't any unreasonable memory usage nor any memory leaks. And the resulting MOV file did appear to be written fairly normal, e.g. the audio data was interleaved with the video data as one would expect.

So, why would I ever set expectsMediaDataInRealTime to NO if there is no apparent downside to setting it to YES? Does this only apply when using an Apple API to read data (using AVAssetReader)? The documentation says that this property controls writing "media data in an ideal interleaving pattern for efficiency in storage and playback," but when expectsMediaDataInRealTime is set to YES, isReadyForMoreMediaData never returns NO and the file appears to be written perfectly. So, if the AVAssetWriter can do this when this property set to YES, why can't it do it when set to NO? The source is exactly the same.

What, exactly, does this property do other than "ensure that the value of readyForMoreMediaData is calculated appropriately" (which means absolutely nothing to me)?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, setting expectsMediaDataInRealTime to YES means the encoder is expecting real-time data stream feeds, such as camera, etc.. In such case, you will be constantly feeding the encoder with data, isReadyForMoreMediaData will tell you whether you can feed data to the encoder. If isReadyForMoreMediaData is NO, you will have to drop the current sample, and wait until next sample arrives and check isReadyForMoreMediaData again for whether it's YES.

On the other hand, if expectsMediaDataInRealTime is NO, means the encoder is not taking a real-time source, but an offline data stream, for instance, AVAssetReader. In this case, because you can control the flow speed by yourself, therefore, upon isReadyForMoreMediaData is NO, you can hold the input and encoder and wait till isReadyForMoreMediaData turns into YES(for instance, use a infinite loop to sleep and wait for the isReadyForMoreMediaData changes, etc.).

The purpose of this I assume is for an internal mechanism to try to interleave audio and video timestamp as aligned as possible, therefore, it will not take the players, decoders to pre-fetch way to much data for playback. It's a compromise between data source end data integrity and playback side experience. Although, I suppose you can use expectsMediaDataInRealTime to YES all the time, but it's better to discard early fed samples in case isReadyForMoreMediaData==NO.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this, this isn't perfect naming and it's little confusing.

`expectsMediaDataInRealTime` means frame are pushed to `AVAssetWriter` - doesn't matter if they are pushed 30FPS, from camera, or from file... it just means that `AVAssetWriter` is to process frame when it comes.

If it is set to `false`, then you should pull frames, ask for them from the source. So it has nothing to do with `realTime`, it is to define if `AVAssetWriter` is to pull frame when ready, or is to be forced to be ready and process it whenever frame is available.

This flag defines who control timing of frames coming to `AVAssetWriter`.